# Python arguments to a function

Tags: python, function, arguments, keyword-argument

Supposing I have a function definition like this:

```
 def temperature(celcius=10, fahr=50):
```

Is there a way to check within the body of the function definition which of the two arguments were actually passed in? As I wrote this question I realized I can manually do it in the contrived example I was thinking about (see code below), but is there a generalized way to do it for functions with a an arbitrary number of kw arguments?

```
class Temperature(object):
  def __init__(self, celcius=10, fahrheneit=50):
    if celcius != 10:
        self._celcius=celcius
        self._fahr=celcius*1.8 + 32
    else:
        if fahrheneit != 50:
            self._fahr=fahrheneit
            self._celcius=5.0*(fahrheneit - 32)/9.0
        else:
            self._celcius=celcius
            self._fahr=fahrheneit
  @property
  def fahr(self):
    return self._fahr

  @fahr.setter
  def fahr(self, f):
    if f < -459.66:
        raise ValueError("Temperature below absolute 0 (-459.66F) is not possible")
    self._fahr=f
    self._celcius=5.0*(f-32)/9.0

  @property
  def celcius(self):
    return self._celcius

  @celcius.setter
  def celcius(self,c):
    if c < -273.15:
        raise ValueError("Temperature below absolute 0 (-273.15 celcius) is not possible")
    self._celcius=c
    self._fahr=1.8*c+32
```

Comment: If you're receiving a `**kwargs` variable, you could just check if the key exists in there.

Comment: The usual way to do this is to assign a default value of `None`.  Then any numeric values received must have been explicitly passed in.

Comment: You can make different constructors for them using ``@staticmethod``. For example ``Temperature.from_celcius(value)``.  Then you can drop the arguments in the ``__init__`` and just use 0C as a default value.